# are anchor tags no longer a standard way to display text in modern web apps?

Tags: reactjs

I started web dev back in the late 90's.  At that time, it was pretty standard to use anchor tags to display text like:

```
<a>Here's some text</a>
```

I just created a new React project, using VSCode as my editor.  The linter is displaying the following message for my anchor text above:

> The href attribute is required for an anchor to be keyboard
> accessible. Provide a valid, navigable address as the href value.

I don't want the overhead of configuring a "navigable address" for simple text that I want to display on the web page.  So what's the recommended tag for simply displaying some text on a webpage in React?

Comment: I don't understand. Why enclose the text in tags at all? Why not simply include `Here's some text` directly in the webpage?

Comment: b/c I need to wrap it with styling.  for example - to set the font size to 25

Comment: Ah. Consider using the `<span>` tag.

Comment: If you want it for styling, use CSS and a `<span/>`. Throwing an anchor around for styling will give accessibility users a terrible experience. Its not that are no longer a standard way to display text, it's that they were *never* to be used that way.

Answer (score 1):

I'd say `<p>` or `<span>` if you're not needing the href attribute.